# C++ - Simple hello world doesn't work in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I've just started programming in c++ and I've a problem that is probably really simple but I've been trying to solve it for a long time.
Cout prints all built-in variables but when I try to print a string variable, it doesn't work (it doesn't print anything even if there are other couts with other things to print that aren't strings).

In short, **when there's a string variable in the code, nothing works**, at least that is what I noticed.

That doesn't print anything

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string greeting="hello";
    cout << greeting;
    }
```

But that works:

```
    cout << "hello";
```

I've tried the same exact code in online editors and it does work.

### EDIT 1:

In the computer's terminal, this is what is shown: procedure entry point is not found ... in the dinamic link library ...

Path:
This is the mingw path: C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin

### EDIT 2

Finally solved it. I've copied the `libstdc++` and the `libgcc` to where I have the .exe.Thank you all for your support. Special thanks to @HolyBlackCat.

Comment: How do you build the program? How do you run the program? Where do you expect the output to be written?

Comment: Tip: If you're just learning C++ then avoid `using namespace std` and embrace the `std::` prefix. It exists for a reason. Removing it confuses your code with Standard Library code.

Comment: Have you tried fushing the standard output buffer after printing, with an `std::endl` for example ?

Comment: Try `cout << greeting << std::flush;` or `cout << greeting << std::endl;`

Comment: I've downloaded mingw. I'm totally new to c++ (I've programmed in other languages), to run the program i do g++ -o first first.cpp (first.cpp is the name of the program).

Comment: `g++ -o first first.cpp` ***builds*** the source file `first.cpp` into the exeuctalbe program `first`, but it doesn't run the program.

Comment: @m88 [In most other usual interactive I/O scenarios, std::endl is redundant when used with std::cout because any input from std::cin, output to std::cerr, or program termination forces a call to std::cout.flush()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, i know it. Sorry, I've forgotten to say that then I run first

Comment: please post a [mcve]. You must have some includes and `using namespace std;` otherwise neither of the codes should compile

Comment: @m88. I've tried those two commands but still doesn't print anything.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818. Yes, at the top I've written `#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;`

Comment: Are you sure VSCode doesn't just ignore the last output line for some reason? What does `cout << std::string("hello") << endl << 42 << endl;` do?

Comment: @m88. That doesn't print anything. However if I do `cout << "hello"<< endl << 42 << endl;` it does work

Comment: How about `std::string greeting = "Hello";  std::cout << greeting.c_str();`

Comment: @BenVoigt it doesn't work.

Comment: @SamuelMolinaPerales: No errors and no output?  What about `std::string greeting = "Hello";   std::cout << "World";`

Comment: Nevermind. now I see your error popup.

Comment: In the .json you will have to remove the part that says `Escriba el nombre del programa; por ejemplo,` and leave just `${workspaceFolder}/first.exe`  It will eventually be worth getting your debugger working, but it won't help with the DLL problem you are having now.

Comment: If you aren't specifically required to use g++ and VS Code, you will probably have a much much easier time with Visual Studio Community Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to errors like "procedure entry point is not found" is:

- Make a list of all `.dll`s located in your compiler's `bin` directory.
- Go through `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\System32` and make sure none of those dlls are there. If you find any, move them somewhere else (or delete them).
- Add your compiler's `bin` directory to the `PATH`, as the first entry.

Comment: You mean to check if the .dlls files that are in the compilers bin are in  `C:\Windows\System32` and delete those files, right? If so, any of these files is in that path.

Comment: @SamuelMolinaPerales Yes, delete those duplicate dlls from `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: There aren't any duplicate files.

Comment: @SamuelMolinaPerales Then continue to the next step.

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know what I can be doing bad...

Comment: @SamuelMolinaPerales Can you show the contents of your PATH?

Comment: Sure, I've put it in the question.

Comment: @SamuelMolinaPerales Do you have any other installations of MinGW? If you have more than one, uninstall the rest. Also can you show the exact error message the debugger gives you?

Comment: @SamuelMolinaPerales Also your screenshot of PATH is cut off. Can you post a full one?

Comment: I've written it below it.

Comment: I've also written what the debugger says. Keep in mind that I don't really know how to use it.

Comment: @SamuelMolinaPerales You provided a different error before. You said "procedure entry point is not found", but now you're showing something else. Why?

Comment: Sorry, That is said when I try to run the program in the computer's terminal. If i do it in vs code terminal, that doesn't happen

Comment: @SamuelMolinaPerales After doing what I suggested, does it work in the terminal? In VSC it doesn't work because your json is wrong, specifically `"program"`. You're supposed to set it to the actual path to your .exe.

Comment: I've added the error message when I run it on the terminal. I'm really sorry, I still don't know a lot about programming, thanksa lot  for all your support.

Comment: @SamuelMolinaPerales Not sure why it doesn't work. Did you restart your console after updating PATH? If not, do it and try again. Otherwise, in your compiler `bin` directory, find the dll that's named something like `libstdc++`, and check again that there are no dlls with the same name in `C:\Windows` (and any subdirectories). If it doesn't help, copy that dll (and also the `libgcc` one) to the directory where you have your .exe.

Comment: Finally solved it. I've copied those two files to where I have the .exe. THANK YOU A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

I should see the whole code, but considering it doesn't work only with a `string`, probably you didn't use the `namespace std`:
Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string greeting = "Hello";

    cout << greeting;
}
```

If it doesn't work, show me the whole code and I'll see if I can help!

Comment: I've added it to the question.